# how can I update a model with custom idAttribute

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

in my simple backbone application, I am trying to update a model and every time it send a put request instead of post.

Well, this is my model named **categoryModel**

```
define(['Backbone'], function (Backbone) {
var CategoryModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        ID: '',
        Name: 'Empty',
        TagID: '0',
        GID: '0'
    },
    idAttribute: "ID",
    initialize: function () {
        if (!this.get('Name')) {
            this.set({ 'Name': this.defaults.Name });
        }
    }
});

return CategoryModel;
});
```

this is the collection

```
define(['Backbone','../../models/categories/categoryModel'], function (Backbone, categoryModel) {
var CategoryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/parentcategory/Actions',
    model: categoryModel
   });

return new CategoryCollection;
});
```

here are my methods in the view

on a `keychange event`

```
createNewItem: function (e) {
    var $this = $(e.currentTarget);
    $('#selectedCategoryName').html($this.val());
    //it creates a new model
    globals.NewCategory = new CategoryModel({ Name: $this.val() });
}
```

on `handleDrop event`

```
handleDropEvent: function (event, ui) {
var draggable = ui.draggable;
//check if name has set
if (!globals.NewCategory) {
    alert("Please write a category name");
    $('#createNewCategory').focus();
    return;
}
//get itemID
var itemID = draggable.attr("id").split('_')[1];
var itemDesc = draggable.attr("id").split('_')[0];
//check items category
if (itemDesc == "Tag") {
    //check if tagID already exists
    if (globals.NewCategory.TagID) {
        alert("you have already specify a tag from this category");
        return;
    }
    globals.NewCategory.set("TagID", itemID);
} else if (itemDesc == "gTag") {
    if (globals.NewCategory.GID) {
        alert("you have already specify a tag from this category");
        return;
    }
    globals.NewCategory.set("GID", itemID);
}
categoriesCollection.create(globals.NewCategory, {
    silent: true,
    wait: true,
    success: function (model, response) {
        model.set("ID", response);
        alert(model.id);
    }
});
}
```

The **categoriesCollection.create** is called twice. Firstly for setting the TagID (on a success request it gets an ID ) and secondly for setting the GID. 
Since the ID has been set, shouldn't had sent a POST request instead of PUT on the second call?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard behaviour is to send a `POST` if the model is new ( doesn't have an ID attributed ) and send a `PUT` if the model id is set.

In your case it's working as designed, if you want it to use `POST` to send UPDATES you have to override [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) to work as you need, but I think it's easier for you to make your backend RESTful and create a `PUT` listener controller method for updates.

Another thing, if I got it right you are using `create()` to update models in your collection, I would advise you not to do that and instead use the `save()` directly in the model you want to update, the code will be a lot more readable.

Cheers.

Comment: the problem was that I had an empty string value in the model initialization for the ID property. That's why the request was always put instead of post. Nevertheless, your suggestions are very welcome